# Regarding a problem with the & operator to perform bitwise operations using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to make a program that:

1. generate a random list of 20 numbers between 0 and 100 and store it in an array;
2. detect which of them fulfills the condition of being bit0 = 0;
3. generate a new list with the elements of 2;
4. detect which elements of this new array meet the condition of being bit2 = 1;
5. store the 4. numbers in a new arrangement

With the following code I have managed to implement functions 1,2 and 3...:

```
    import numpy as np
    print("Ejercicios Vectores :\n")

    datos1 = []
    datos2 = []
    datos3 = []
    
    def buscar(s):
        conta=0
        for num in (s):
            if num & 1 == 0:
                conta += 1
        return conta
    
    for num in range (20):
        datos1.append(np.random.randint(0,100))
        arreglo1 = np.array(datos1)
        c1 = buscar(arreglo1)


    for num in arreglo1:
        if num & 1 == 0:
            datos2.append(bin(num))
            arreglo2 = np.array(datos2)
    


    print('Arreglo que almacena 20 números aleatorios entre 0 y 100 :\n', arreglo1)
    print('La cantidad de números con bit0 = 0 es :', c1)
    print('Arreglo con los', c1 ,'números bit0 = 0 del arreglo anterior :\n', arreglo2)
```

The result of this code is correct:

```
    Arreglo que almacena 20 números aleatorios entre 0 y 100 :
    [62 88 94 68  0 88 22 88 62 27 18 23 75 57 31 51 75 32  2  3]
    La cantidad de números con bit0 = 0 es : 12
    Arreglo con los 12 números bit0 = 0 del arreglo anterior :
    ['0b111110' '0b1011000' '0b1011110' '0b1000100' '0b0' '0b1011000'
    '0b10110' '0b1011000' '0b111110' '0b10010' '0b100000' '0b10']
```

but when I try to add functionality 4 and 5 I get the following error:

Watch this:

```
    import numpy as np
    print("Ejercicios Vectores :\n")
    datos1 = []
    datos2 = []
    datos3 = []
    
    def buscar(s):
        conta=0
        for num in (s):
            if num & 1 == 0:
                conta += 1
        return conta
    
    for num in range (20):
        datos1.append(np.random.randint(0,100))
        arreglo1 = np.array(datos1)
        c1 = buscar(arreglo1)

    for num in arreglo1:
        if num & 1 == 0:
            datos2.append(bin(num))
            arreglo2 = np.array(datos2)
    
    for num in arreglo2:
        if num & 4 == 4:
            datos3.append(bin(num))
           
    print('Arreglo que almacena 20 números aleatorios entre 0 y 100 :\n', arreglo1)
    print('La cantidad de números con bit0 = 0 es :', c1)
    print('Arreglo con los', c1 ,'números bit0 = 0 del arreglo anterior :\n', arreglo2)
    print(datos3)
```

AND THE ERROR AS I SAID IS:

```
    if num & 4 == 4:
    TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for &: 'numpy.str_' and 'int'.
```

Apparently python cannot perform the operation because the & operator cannot match a string with an integer. However I don't understand why it can run to perform 2 and 3 correctly, but from then on it doesn't work any more.

Comment: `bin(num)` returns a string. If you want to do bitwise operations, don't convert the number to a string.

Comment: Genius! It works, thank you so much.